# Using sybmols to clarify what needs to be surveyed (Dates)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

What I need is for QGIS to symbolise what needs to be surveyed in a particular season.  Running from April to April on a given year.  I have put this into QGIS, but it shows me any records I change.  So the start date is 1st April 2021, can someone please clarify where I am going wrong.

"date1" ='NULL'< '2021.04.01'OR
"date2" ='NULL' < '2021.04.01'OR
"date3"  ='NULL' < '2021.04.01'OR
"date4"  ='NULL' < '2021.04.01'OR
"date5"  ='NULL' < '2021.04.01'OR
"date6"  ='NULL' < '2021.04.01'OR
"date7"  ='NULL' < '2021.04.01'OR
"date8"  ='NULL'< '2021.04.01'OR
"date9"  ='NULL' < '2021.04.01'OR
"date10" ='NULL'< '2021.04.01'

Comment: What exactly should this expression do? Because right now you check whether your dates are equal to NULL and smaller than a string. This wont work twice.

Comment: I think I need to use less than a date:  "date1" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date2" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date3" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date4" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date5" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date6" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date7" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date8" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date9" > '2021.04.01'OR
 "date10" > '2021.04.01'

Comment: I still have no idea, what condition you're trying to check for.

Comment: How are your date stored ? in a date or datetime field or as text, ? if as text you will need to convert to date for the comparaison to work as you intend